# Maintaining persistent connection and push event when desired

Tags: javascript, c#, server-sent-events

I have trying work around Server Sent Events. I have to push event from different server and on user response.
I have consumer on `localhost:A` and server on `localhost:B`

What i want to do is push event only when i click on **Push Event Button**.
and establish the persistent connection through event channel.

**localhostA js**

```
    function contentLoaded() {
        var source = new EventSource('https://localhost:44398/home/message', {
            withCredentials: true
        });
        //var ul = $("#messages");
        source.onmessage = function (e) {

            var li = document.createElement("li");
            var returnedItem = e.data;
            li.textContent = returnedItem;
            $("#messages").append(li);
        }

        source.onerror = function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
    };
```

**localhostB Server Action Method**

```
        public IActionResult Message(int id = 0)
        {
            var result = string.Empty;
            var sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendFormat("retry: 10000\n\n");
            sb.AppendFormat("data: {0} {1}\n\n", "hello",id);
            Response.Headers.Add("Connection", "keep-alive");
            var a = Response.HttpContext.Connection.Id;
            return Content(sb.ToString(), "text/event-stream");
        }
```

**localhostB client side**

```
 <button onclick="javascript:sendEvent()">Push Event</button>
```

**localhostB js**

```
<script>
    var sendEvent = function () {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open("POST", "/home/message?id=4");
        xhr.onload = function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
        xhr.onerror = function (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
        xhr.send();
    }
</script>
```